# relative link in vue returns with nothing

Tags: vue.js, url, hyperlink, components, relative-path

I have got two components in vue, one with lightbox for images and one for playing audio. I got relative links to the assets but either the images or the audio is being displayed and played. First I thought it was an issue with the component itself but since it doesnt work on either of these it might be something else.

If I provide an absolut url it works however fine for some reason

This doesnt work either when I build the application or locally:

```
export default {
      components: {
        VueLitebox,
        "vue-audio": VueAudio
      },
      data() {
        return {
          // AUDIO
          file1: "../assets/music/myfile.mp3",

          // LITEBOX
          images: [
            ".../assets/img/myimage.jpg",
```

This works fine:

```
export default {
  components: {
    VueLitebox,
    "vue-audio": VueAudio
  },
  data() {
    return {
      // AUDIO
      file1: "http://mypage.com/music/myfile.mp3",

      // LITEBOX
      images: [
        "http://mypage.com/img/myimage.jpg",
```

I can of course upload the images and music separate and make it work but it feels a bit inconvenient.

What can be wrong?

**UPDATE:**

Thanks for the answers. Now I got two methods. And both actually works.

One is to put all my assets in the public folder. That solved it with a link like:

```
"/assets/img/myimage.jpg",
```

The other way is to using require.

```
require("../assets/img/myimage.jpg"),
```

Both works but is there a prefered way?

Comment: Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52083358/3226121)

Answer (score 1):

You should use **require** when using assets

```
file1: require("../assets/music/myfile.mp3")
```

Without require webpack won’t know that you want to bundle that asset and your path will remain unchanged. Actually webpack knows how to handle this kind of files thru the use of plugins and not out of the box.

Regarding the fact that it works with absolute path and not relative ones.
Your relative path is valid in the local file system on your dev server. When deploying the app you are not running in the local file system, but on the web. Even though relative paths are resolved using a similar algorithm, your results will depend on the URL where the component is used and not on the path of the vue file.

For example if the component is rendered on a URL of the form

```
https://example.com/list/
```

The relative path would resolve to **https://example.com/assets** which is probably what you want. But on the following URL

```
 https://example.com/list/1/
```

Will resolve to **https://example.com/list/assest** which isn’t what you’d expect.

Webpack takes care of this problems (to some degree, you need to be sure that you don’t mess up the **base** tag).

Comment: Thanks! Now I got two methods. And both actually works. One is to put all my assets in the public folder. That solved it with a link like: ´"/assets/img/myimage.jpg", ´ The other way is to using require.  require("../assets/img/myimage.jpg"),  Is there a prefered way?

Comment: I don’t think so. Keep in mind that the absolute path solution will only work for the assets folder. The default vuejs template also has a assets golder under src and for that you must ise require