# How do I link to a pdf in vue?

Tags: vue.js

I'm trying to create a link on my vue app to local pdf files. Right now here's my problem.

My pdfs are located in assets/static/ and presently linking to them like this.

```
<template>
  <div id="forms" class="view-wrapper">
      <h3>Downloadable Forms</h3>
      <a href="../assets/static/Direct Deposit Form.pdf">Claim Form</a>
  </div>
</template>
```

This brings up a link on the page, but when I click it, I'm taken to a blank page on my app with just the navbar and footer and nothing in between. I'm hoping to have it bring up the document in the browsers pdf viewer in another tab. Some help would be greatly appreciated.

Edit: SOLVED: @dan helped me realize that I just had to use one dot to access my assets folder.

Comment: If you want to serve files from the server, you should put them in `public` instead of `src/assets`, which is for bundling files in the client.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52082968/vue-js-2-vue-cannot-find-files-from-assets-folder-v-for/52083292#52083292

Comment: I tried moving a file into public, and then linking to it with an <a> tag, and it's still just opening a blank page with just my header and footer.

Comment: Once it's in `public > assets > static`, you can do this:  `<a href="./assets/static/Direct Deposit Form.pdf">Claim Form</a>`  Use one dot, not two.

Comment: That finally worked! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

To render a pdf in the browser use an `<iframe src="path-to-pdf" />`. Unless you're binding reactive data to the element you don't have to do anything different in vue. Check out https://stackoverflow.com/a/52644970/6890774 this is a similar issue.

Comment: Thank you, but I am actually trying to bring up the pdf in a new tab. I'm copying a static site that uses <a href="path" target="_blank">Click</a>, and brings up the pdf in the browsers pdf viewer in another tab. Any ideas for that?

Comment: Got it. Why don't you link to a new page using `target="_blank"` and then on that page have the iframe there with the rendered pdf. Also, check out this thread theres several ways to accomplish rendering a pdf in the browser.