# Different image paths between dev and prod for vue require

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, frontend

I have the following architecture:

```
ProjectName
  - dist
    - img
    - index.html
  - src
    - assets
      - fonts
      - img
  - public
      - img
```

I save static images in `ProjectName/src/assets/img/`

And save dynamic images (images that user uploaded) in public folder with path `ProjectName/public/img` from my Flask backend. I'm doing this because I want to get image on the fly without use webpack build

So, I can view images in `developer` mode use

`return require('../../public/img/paintings/'+imgName)`

But when I use `production` mode I must write without first `../`

`return require('../public/img/paintings/'+imgName)`

Because `dist` folder has shorter path to `public` folder than non build project

How I come to agreement with different paths and don't change code before build?

Answer (score 0):

I think I found solution for my problem.

I read answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/52083358/10683019 and understood that `require` using `src` folder and all works after changed `return` like in answer